# What is the best way to use Amazon Cognito with Google (.NET Framework)?

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, google-api, uwp

I am a UWP app developer to begin.

Okay, so I've decided to use the Google APIs SDK to authenticate users and then pass the generated token to Cognito (CognitoAWSCredentials object).

It at least APPEARS to work that way. First I'd like to know if that is the most efficient approach to getting AWS credentials or is there a better modern way.

Also, it appears that the Google token expires every hour and Cognito doesn't automatically request a token refresh on its own. What is a good approach to check that a token will soon expire and automatically refresh the token before this happens?

Comment: Did you go over the docs?

Comment: Yes. Didn't find anything sort of tutorial or any documentation that went into the specifics regarding these matters. Quite typical of companies that roll out SDKs for the Windows platform as of late. .NET is an afterthought for them. SMH.